Whisper api transcribing in firefox but not in chrome
I want to transcribe my audio into text, so I am using the whisper v3-large model's api. I first send my audiofile to the server, where I use multer to allow for my request object to access the file using req.file,and then I pass the file's buffer to the runReplicate function.
app.post("/replicate", upload.single("audio"), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!req.file) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "No audio file received" });
    }
    console.log(
      "Received audio file:",
      req.file.originalname,
      "Size:",
      req.file.size
    );
    const result = await runReplicate(req.file.buffer);
    res.json(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in /replicate endpoint:", error);
    res.status(500).json({
      error: "An error occurred during transcription",
      details: error.message,
    });
  }
});

Here is the runReplicate function

const runReplicate = async (audioBuffer) => {
  try {
    // Convert buffer to Base64
    const base64Audio = audioBuffer.toString("base64");
    
    const mimeType = "audio/mpeg";

    const input = {
      audio: `data:${mimeType};base64,${base64Audio}`,
    };


    const output = await replicate.run(
      process.env.WHISPER_MODEL,
      { input }
    );
    return { text: output.transcription };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in runReplicate:", error);
    if (error.response) {
      console.error("Replicate API response:", await error.response.text());
    }
    throw error;
  }
};

I was expecting consistent behavior across browsers, however even after introducing a setTimeout of 60 seconds, I wasn't able to make it work on chrome.

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setTimeout(60000, () => {
    console.log("Request has timed out.");
    res.sendStatus(408);
  });
  next();
});


I am getting the whisper error as: {"error":"An error occurred during transcription","details":"Prediction failed: 'duration'"}
Any help would be much appreciated!
